# Javascript Create Object with property that is dynamic

Tags: javascript

```
    <body>
        <div id="player" style="position: absolute; left: 30px;">Hello</div>
        <script>
            function Player (element) {
                this.element = element;
                this.left = element.style.left;
            }

            var player = new Player(document.querySelector('#player'));
            console.log(player.left);
        </script>
    </body>
```

I have something above. If I call console.log(player.left). It return me `30px`. Then I change left property (in dev tool). I still get `30px` . The question is Whether it have a way that `left property of Player class` can change value dynamically whenever I change that element's left OR I have to assign value: `player.left = document.querySelector("#player").style.left` again?

Comment: Look into definePropery and getters in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
  function Player(element)
  {
      this.element = element;
      this.left = function ()
      {
          return this.element.style.left
      };
  }

  var player = new Player(document.querySelector('#player'));
  console.log(player.left()); //30px

  setTimeout(function () //test
  {
     document.querySelector('#player').style.left='100px'
      console.log(player.left()); //100px
  }, 2000)
```

http://jsbin.com/dilihofi/4/edit

*missread your question at first deleted answer

Comment: yes, it maybe be a way when change left from propery to method. But what about left still be property?

Comment: well you could use `__defineGetter__` but it's only IE11+ . (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter)

Comment: #Royi Namir. you 're right. some browsers support it. Still I need some casual way

Comment: Getters and setters are eventually just methods. no need to hide that fact

Comment: p.s. if you dont want to "uglify" the Player ctor function - you could add the getter method to the prototype...